# How do I create an expanding textbox?

Tags: html, css, text, textbox, expand

I want to create a textbox that physically expands. I want the width of the box to be 265 pixels and when you paste text into the box it expands downwards. I tried using the code from this website http://bgrins.github.io/ExpandingTextareas/ but when I run the code it generates a different textbox. I want one that actually physically gets longer exactly as shown on that website but when I run the code it creates a box that doesn't grow. Instead it only expands within and creates a scroll bar.

Comment: you may also try this one.. http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the plugin is not working at all for you, so I would just double-check the basics:

- Do you have jQuery (required for the plugin) and the plugin JS included on your page correctly?
- Do you have `class="expanding"` on your `textarea` tag?

The plugin seems to work fine overall - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/32ysj/).

**Update:** I've noticed this plugin doesn't seem to work on IE 11 (haven't tried other versions), but seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox.